# Lyrics in Green Day's "Jesus Of Suburbia"

Tags: lyrics

I am a huge green day fan and listen to many of their songs. Most of the lyrics are pretty straightforward to understand what they are talking about but there is one line that puzzles me.

At 5:40 on their song [Jesus Of Suburbia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZFmaMbkUD4) they say *"I don't care if you don't care"* but I can't tell if Armstrong means *"I don't care whether you don't care"* or *"I won't care if you won't care"*

Answer (score 1):

While I think it's likely that Armstrong does intend *both* meanings, what textual evidence there is suggests the meaning, "I don't care [about the fact that] you don't care."

I'm basing this on the fact that he ends that same section of the song with the statement "it don't believe in me... and I don't care!"  If we go with the above meaning for the ambiguous phrase, then both versions are expressing pretty much the same thing.